# Putting equations in parametric form

Tags: 3d, parametric

Im told that an object has the following trajectory:

$$
\begin{gather}
T= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x^2 + y^2 &= 4\\
x + z &=3
\end{array} \right.
\end{gather}
$$

We are also told that the object makes a full tour around T.

I'm asked to put T in parametric form, but I don't understand how, since there is no $t$ in the equation.

And also, I don't understand what it means when they say that the object makes a full tour around T. Does that mean T is a circle?

Comment: The whole art of parametrizing is to _introduce_ $t$ suitably. :) Your $T$ isn't a circle, but _is_ a closed loop. To start, do you know how to put the circle $x^{2} + y^{2} = 4$, $z = 0$ into parametric form? (There are infinitely many correct answers, but one usually stands out.)

Comment: $ x=2 \cos(t) $ and $ y = 2 \sin(t)$ ... $z= ?$ ...

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Ok, yes I know how put a circle in parametric form.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang,  Is it an elipse? I get $$
\begin{gather}
T= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x &=2\cos(t)\\
y&=2\sin(t)\\
z&=3-2\cos(t)
\end{array} \right.
\end{gather}
$$

Comment: Probably neater to write 
$$
T(u) = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \cos u \\ 2 \sin u \\ 3 - 2 \cos u
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: @LiamF-A: Yes, that works (as is what I would have written). :)

Answer (score 2):

In the $(xy) $ plane, the trajectory is the circle of center $(0,0) $ and radius $2$.

in the space, the object moves on a cylindrical surface defined by the parametric equations:

$$x=2\cos (t) $$
$$y=2\sin (t) $$
$$z=3-x=3-2\cos (t) $$

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi Since you have f x^2+y^2=4$, this means that $-2\le x \le 2$. We cannot have $x=3$. if so $y^2=-5 !!$

Comment: \ I see that you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting an interpretation:

Let me write $\theta$  instead of  t:

$x = 2 cos(\theta)$ ;  $y = 2 sin(\theta)$ :  $z = 3 - 2 cos(\theta)$ .

In vector form:

$\vec{r}$ = $(0,0,3)$ + $2( cos(\theta), sin(\theta), - cos(\theta) )$.

$\vec{r} = (0,0,3) + \vec{r'}$

Let's look at the direction vector  $\vec{r'}$:

$\vec{r'} = 2( cos(\theta), sin(\theta), - cos(\theta) )$.

Projection of path onto the $x -, y -$ plane is a circle, I.e. the object moves on a cylinder, radius = $2$.
Cylinder axis parallel to $z$ - axis.

The $z$ component describes a $cos$ curve.

The projection of the path onto the $y-, z-$ plane  is again a circle, centre at $y = 0$, $z = 3$, I.e. the object moves on a cylinder, radius = $2$.
Cylinder axis parallel to $x$ - axis

The x component describes a $cos$ curve.

Comments welcome.

Comment: Wouldnt $\vec{r'} = 2(-sin(\theta),cos(\theta),sin(\theta)) ?$

Comment: @Liam F-A. Above parametrization is not unique. Choose another parameter $\theta =  (π/2 - \theta ')$. You get $2(sin(\theta '),cos(\theta '), -sin(\theta ')).$ Yet another parameter:$ \theta ''$ = $- \theta ' $ yields your parametrization. Makes sense?